# Power supply transformer question, double primary

Tags: power-supply, transformer, mains, ac-dc

I'm trying to make a circuit to look like this one:
[image: Power supply from Aplication Note]

This is from ATM90E26 [Application note](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-46102-SE-M90E26-ApplicationNote.pdf), this IC needs to be connected to mains in order to measure voltage (220VAC) and current. I tried to look for information about the transformer "TD35-18A-220V"(turns ratio, inductance, etc) but with no luck, all I found was a link to buy bulks of 1000 pieces and no specifications.

So I started to look for a similar one and found this one from wurth elektronik: [750342104](https://ar.mouser.com/datasheet/2/445/750342104-1724037.pdf)

[image: transformer symbol]   [image: transformer table]

According to datasheet for [78L33](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1234799/HAOHAI/78L33/1) maximum input voltage is 18V, so the position of terminal 2 of the transformer (I mean the ratio of (1-2):(2-4)) should be specific to get that output level from terminals 2 and 4, as in the circuit on the first image (terminals 3-1).

From isolated side (terminals 6-10) should be power for digital control electronics, microcontroller and the rest of the circuit (250mA top current). And an isolator ([SI8651BB-B-IS1R](https://ar.mouser.com/datasheet/2/368/si865x_datasheet-1522760.pdf) )to connect the microcontroller to the non-isolated from mains ATM90E26 IC.

My question is if I'm looking at this the correct way?

Is the turns ratio for (1-2):(2-4) a percentage style ratio?, meaning if 220V is the voltage between 1-4, then, if I looking to obtain 15v between 2-4, terminal 2 will be at the 6.81% of the turns between 1-4?

Does this means that the transformer needs to be specific and not "off the shelf"?

Thank you!

Comment: No, it's a SMPS transformer, not a mains 50/60Hz. Ask ATMEL for the specifications, if they are serious company they should tell you.

Comment: Anyway, it seems weird at first glance, like using L as ground and then depicted turns ratio 1-3 VS.  3-5 is huge that goes to supply 3.3V LDO. I mean it's like powering the 3.3V LDO with 300V and connecting phase line (L) to frame ground?? You'd better go away from this design if you don't want to hurt yourself, IMO this is not the correct schematics.

Comment: Hello @MarkoBuršič , the things is that in order for the metering IC to measure voltage it needs to be connected to L and N. Through a connection GND-L and a voltage divider circuit for N (880KΩ-1KΩ).

Comment: Responding to your first comment @MarkoBuršič, if it is a SMPS (switch mode power supply) then I should add a switching IC right? Or should I look for another transformer?

Comment: I understand that, but it could be made more safe. For example using an isolated DC/DC small power converter from MCU side 5V/5V and LDO 3.3V, then using digital signal isolator IC for communication between Atmel IC and MCU, you can connect and swap L or N to the Atmel side. Designing a SMPS would be even tougher than this metering app. so I don't advise you.

Comment: Perhaps I can help a little here.  In the schematic I think that the ground/earth symbol is there to allow simulation software to work, or as an indication of what to use as a reference when considering other voltages in the circuit; it isn’t a suggestion that you actually connect live to ground (that would be silly at best).  The transformer in question looks like a fairly standard step-down device except that it has that extra tapping on the primary, that’s effectively acting as an autotransformer.  If you can find a transformer with different input tappings (220-230-240) then you can...

Comment: Use these.  So if you connect neutral to the 230 tapping you should get 10Vrms from the 220 tapping, which will be ample to provide your 3V3 rail.

Comment: Hello @Frog , so I should find a transformer with a tapping somewhere near the L connection? So this sentence is correct (from my question) : "Is the turns ratio for (1-2):(2-4) a percentage style ratio?, meaning if 220V is the voltage between 1-4, then, if I looking to obtain 15v between 2-4, terminal 2 will be at the 6.81% of the turns between 1-4?"

Comment: @Iván Gerber Yes, that's right.  Lots of mains transformers have exactly that (slightly fewer these days since 230V is increasingly standard but a few years back 220/230/240 was quite common).  Yes the voltage on each turn of the primary and secondary is constant, so 2300 turns (say) on the primary would require 150 turns on the secondary to produce 15VAC.  Bear in mind that's RMS voltage, so with a half-wave rectifier (D1) you'll get a 21V peak at 50Hz.  Be aware that the linear regulator will have to dissipate quite a bit of power; up to 6 times that consumed by the load.

Comment: Also, don't assume that the resistance of the windings is an indication of the number of turns; the secondary will have thicker wire and therefore a lower resistance per turn.  Inductance is also confusing, as this is proportional to the square of the number of turns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need about 8..12 V DC on the input of 7833 (to have some room for line voltage variation).

When rectified, AC voltage is multiplied by a factor of 1.4. A single rectification diode will give about 1 V voltage drop. So, the required AC voltage would be (8…12)/1.4+1 (V) = 7…10 (V), not 15 V AC.

Since line isolation is not required (at this point), AC voltage may be obtained both by autotransformer and by regular transformer, The turns ratio have to be 220/(7…10). Note, that in case of autotransformer, primary turns would be w1+w2.

It might be easier to find appropriate separate transformer to power ATM90E26 alone than the combined autotransformer shown in the appnote.

[image]

And, for safety reasons, I have to emphasize, that secondary (MCU) part must be fully isolated from the line.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzpDMY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Instead looking for the transformer you can use components already pre-made, like isolated RS485 transceiver module, MCU module, lastly your custom metering module with isolated DC/DC converter and signal isolator IC, like ADUMxxxx

ISO RS485 examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The black bricks on photos are isolated DC/DC converters, while the ICs are digital signals isolators TX,RX,RTS.

The MCU can be any kind of it, for example Arduino, Raspberry PI, ...etc. The SMPS you can buy in any electronic store, like Meanwell, Recom, TDK Lambda, Traco, ...

Meanwell EPS15-05:

[image]

Then you have to choose a small DC/DC converter 5V/3.3V let's say 2W, example Murata MEJ2S0503SC (instead of custom AC transformer):

[image]

Then you need a digital isolator like ADUMxxx or Sixxx for SPI or UART commuinication between your custom board and MCU.

Similar metering application (3 phase) [SmarPi](https://www.enerserve.eu/en/smartpi.html).

[image]

It has an input SMPS, which supplies RPi or Arduino. Through a digital signal isolator and DC/DC converter (all in one) it supplies and communicates with metering IC.

Comment: I think the OP specifically needs some line-referenced circuitry to monitor AC voltage and current, and will then (let us hope) isolate this from the remainder of the low-voltage circuitry.

Comment: Hello @Marko Buršič , I think i understand what you propose. Metering IC needs to be referenced to 220VAC from L, but this will be no problem for DC/DC isolated converter?

Comment: @IvánGerber Correct. The app. note lacks of SPI or UART isolator, which is a must if you have to connect to the board. You could even put a small transformer 230/6VAC and then reference the frame ground to whatever potential: L or N, but the best way is to go with a custom board as described.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič thank you for answering, I will do like you say, using a SMPS and an isolator IC with dc/dc converter to power and comunicate with the non isolated circuit wich will be referenced to L by tying it to it's GND.

Comment: @IvánGerber You can see it in the app. note that L which connects on shunt is tied to circuit ground, so if you connect any isolated supply to Vdd and GND would get L voltage reference on GND, but the dc/dc converter has to have a breakdown voltage larger than line voltage, let's say >=1.5kV or 500VRMS.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič thank you very much, you showed me a new way to isolate a circuit and I will use this method in my design (DC/DC isolated converter). But the question I made was to understand better the way this transformers work, and the user EugeneK responded to it in a simple way I understood. So if it's ok with you I will mark his response as the correct one.

Comment: @IvánGerber I see, now. I thought that the part of autotransformer was clear in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's an 80 kHz transformer so it must be for a switched-mode power supply and typicall will be fed by a high-voltage DC and controlled by a high frequency switching transistor. It won't work at 50/60 Hz.

Try to avoid any connection between mains and your measurement circuit. Full isolation is the way to go. It will make the device much safer and allow debugging, plugging in USB programmer, grounded oscilloscope leads, etc.

You might find some useful design ideas at the [Open Energy Monitor](http://openenergymonitor.org) project. They should be good on safety.

Comment: Hello @Transistor , so what you are saying is that I need to add 80kHz switching IC like in this [example](https://eds.st.com/console/#/app/acdc/ic_acdc_catalogs/filter/%5B%5D/selected/viper318hd:isolated%20flyback) ? Note: metering IC needs to be connected to N and L in order to measure voltage

Comment: What part of the system are you trying to build? The power supply or the mains voltage monitor? You might be approaching this the wrong way in that you seem to be saying "I've chosen to use bass guitar strings, now show me how to make a violin using them".

Comment: I'm trying to build the power supply that will power the metering IC and another isolated circuit, this circuits are done on design already. I'm trying to understand how to design the power supply transformer, and how to find a trnasformer that meets the requirements. I see now that the transformer can't be the one that i posted because is 80kHz rated and I need 50Hz rated

Comment: Just buy one ready made. You can get plug-top USB supplies very cheaply - if you don't have any lying around, take the PCB out and mount it securely in your project. It seems that you are a little over your head on this project so I am very concerned that you will try to measure the mains voltage without an isolating transformer. Understand that if you don't then you must assume that the whole circuit is live and you can't connect it to a USB port or attach your 'scope's ground clips.

Comment: The thing is that already made power supplies don't have the topology that the circuit needs. So I am trying to understad how the turns ratio on this special transformers work in order to know how to better look for them on supplier pages. Thanks to you now I see that I was not looking well because of frecuency rate.

Comment: Then edit your question to write a proper specification for your requirements.

Comment: But in the question, at the end, I ask about the ratios of the primary. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear on the question. I'm not trying to make someone tell me the transformer I need, I'm trying to understand how the transformer works.

Comment: So write a specification: (1) Input voltage = xxx V AC. (2) Output voltage 1 = 5 V DC, 1.2 A. (3) Output voltage 2 = 12 V DC,  0.2 A. (4) Voltage proportional to mains RMS voltage. This will need to be converted to DC for 0 - 5 V ADC input. This signal needs to be isolated from mains. (6) Etc.